# Need help referencing in an array and with number formatting

Tags: java

I'm so lost on an assignment and need a hand!  Basically, I'm suppose to write a code where users can input the number of inches of rain per month for 12 months.  It will calculate the total inches, average inches, plus point out the month with the most and least rain.  I have the total and average inches under control.

The most and least rain is where I'm having issues though.  I know how to write the code to figure out the highest and least amount of rain fall, but I don't know how to get it to actually say which actual month in the output.  It wants me to list the actual number in the array of 12 months, for instance, 7 for the seventh month.

Another issue I'm having is with the Decimal Format.  I've put the import statement at the top, and I put what I thought was the right code in what I thought was the right place in the body, yet when the average is calculated, it still produces a long string of numbers.  ie 12.12121314141, when I want it to display 12.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!  Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Rainfall
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      final int MONTHS = 12;
   double[] rainFall = new double[MONTHS];

   initRain(rainFall);

   DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##0.0");
   System.out.println("The total rainfall for this year is " +      

            totalRain(rainFall));
   System.out.println("The average rainfall for this year is " + 
            averageRain(rainFall));
   System.out.println("The month with the highest amount of rain is " +     
            highest);
   System.out.println("The month with the lowest amount of rain is " +  

            leastRain(rainFall));
        }

   /**
  totalRain method
  @return The total rain fall in the array.
   */

   public static double totalRain(double[] rainFall)
   {
      double total = 0.0;     // Accumulator

  // Accumulate the sum of the elements in the rain fall array
  for (int index = 0; index < rainFall.length; index++)
     //total += rainFall[index];
     total = total + rainFall[index];

  // Return the total.
      return total;
   }

   /**
  averageRain method 
  @return The average rain fall in the array.
   */

   public static double averageRain(double[] rainFall)
   {
      return totalRain(rainFall) / rainFall.length;
   }

   /**
  mostRain method
  @return The most rain in the rain fall array.
   */

   public static double mostRain(double[] rainFall)
   {
  double highest = rainFall[0];

  for (int index = 0; index < rainFall.length; index++)
  {
     if (rainFall[index] > highest)
        highest = rainFall[index];
  }

  return highest;
   }

   /**
  leastRain method
  @returns The least rain in rain fall array.
   */

   public static double leastRain(double[] rainFall)
   {
  double lowest = rainFall[0];

  for (int index = 0; index < rainFall.length; index++)
  {
     if (rainFall[index] < lowest)
        lowest = rainFall[index];
  }

  return lowest;
   }

      /**
  initRain method 
  @return The rain fall array filled with user input
   */
public static void initRain(double[] array)
{
      double input;  // To hold user input.
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
  {
    System.out.print("Enter rain fall for month " + (index + 1)     

            +": ");
    array[index] = scan.nextDouble();
      }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the format issue, make this:

```
System.out.println("The total rainfall for this year is " +      
formatter.format(totalRain(rainFall)));
```

And so on with all return values.

I don't get the issue regarding months thou. Could you explain it a little more?

edit. Okay, I get it. The value of `index` inside the loop when you assign the higuestRain,... values will be the month you are searching for ; )

Comment: Thank you so much for the speedy response!  The formatting works now, but I'm still having issues with the months.  Based on the tip that I got from Rodrigo, here's the code that I wrote for the "highest" portion: `public static double mostRain(double[] rainFall) { double highest = rainFall[0]; for (int index = 0; index < rainFall.length; index++) { if (rainFall[index] > highest) highest = index; } return highest; }`  It's printing an index, but the wrong one. Any thoughts on what could be happening?  Thanks again!

Comment: create a new variable, let's call it int choosenMonth; and then make this: 
  for (int index = 0; index < rainFall.length; index++)
  {
    if (rainFall[index] > highest)
      highest = rainFall[index];
       choosenMonth = index;
  }

Comment: you must declare your variable at the start of the program, this way: int choosenMonth = 0; If not, it will throw an exception (not initialized)

Comment: Glad to help you. Please don't forget ticking the answer if it solved the issue ; )

Answer (score 0):

You defined a DecimalFormat but you never use it in your program. Try

```
System.out.println("The average rainfall for this year is " + formatter.format(averageRain(rainFall)));
```

The Format classes are not global for your application you define them with your formating strings and then use format to pretty print the Number to String or parse to convert a String to Number.

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual month you need to store the index in the array, instead of the value that index contains. In a nutshell you need to replace

```
highest = rainFall[index];
```

with

```
highest = index;
```

And that'll give you a number that goes from 0 to 11, which are the indexes available in an Array with 12 positions. If you want a number from 1 to 12, to be related to our months you can do this:

```
highest = index + 1
```

And as for the Formatter, you're never using it. Java will not use it implicitly if that's what you thought. You need to explicitly invoke it's methods to get the propper result. Something like:

```
formatter.format(totalRain(rainFall));
```

---

**EDIT**

To help you get the idea, here's an implementation of your `mostRain` method

```
public static double mostRain(double[] rainFall){
    double highest = rainFall[0];

    for (int index = 0; index < rainFall.length; index++)
    {
        if (rainFall[index] > rainFall[highest])
            highest = index;
    }

    return highest + 1;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the speedy response!  Now I got the formatting to work, but I'm still having issues with the highest and lowest months.  It appears to be printing an index number now, but it's the wrong one.  Here's the code I put:  `public static double mostRain(double[] rainFall)
   {
      double highest = rainFall[0];

      for (int index = 0; index < rainFall.length; index++)
      {
         if (rainFall[index] > highest)
            highest = index;
      }

      return highest;
   }`

Comment: The indexes in an array with 12 positions will go from 0 to 11, so perhaps the value you want is more like this `highest = index + 1` than you'll always have an answer that goes from 1 to 12

Comment: I had thought that that would be the case, too, so I tried it, but the numbers were still wrong.  These are the numbers that I ran: 10.1, 11.2, 12.3, 13.4, 14.5, 15.6, 5.1, 6.2, 7.3, 8.4, 9.5, 10.0, and when I ran it initially, the output was 10 and 6, then when I ran it with the "+ 1", the output was 10 and 12.  It's suppose to be 6 and 7.

Comment: Your comparison is wrong, you now need to check the value that `highest` index contains. Like this: `if (rainFall[index] > rainFall[highest])` And remember that this can be influenced if you used the `index + 1`, perhaps it would be smarter to add the one only when you print

Comment: @Devora, I added an Edit to help you get started, you can implement the same idea for the other methods

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I finally figured it out.  Thanks so much for taking the time to help.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem at all, @Devora, just don't forget to pick an answer as the correct one, if there is any :-)

Answer (score 0):

For decimal format problem here is solution that you can use.

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Test

{

public static void main(String args[])

{

```
    double i = 12.12121314141;
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.#"); 
    format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    String s = format.format(i);
    i = Double.parseDouble(s);
    System.out.println(i); //should be 12.1
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

To get the index you need 2 variables, one to store the amount of rainfall and the other to remember the index (or month):

```
public static double mostRain(double[] rainFall)
{
  double highest = rainFall[0];
  int monthIndex;

  for (int index = 0; index < rainFall.length; index++)
  {
    if (rainFall[index] > highest)
      highest = rainFall[index];
      monthIndex = index;
  }

  return monthIndex;
}
```

The method will return the index of the month with the highest rainfall, you can then use the index to retrieve the actual amount of rainfall from the array.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  In order to put this piece of code in, would I have to declare monthIndex earlier in the code?  I'm having issues getting this to work.  Sorry, I'm a super noob when it comes to Java!

Comment: Declare it in the `mostRain()` method, the same place I have in the example I gave.

Comment: For some reason, it's giving me a very long error message when I replace my existing code with this.  It starts off like this: `Rainfall.java:80: error: variable highestMonth might not have been initialized
      return highestMonth;`

Comment: You also need to initialize it `int highestMonth = 0;` so it will default to index 0 if the loop for some reason does not assign it a value.

Comment: Thanks so much, Adam.  I'm not sure what's going on, the code took and it's giving me index numbers, but not the correct ones, and it's not off by + 1.

Comment: No problem, post your new code and I will try to see what the problem is.

Comment: Hey Adam, I was finally able to figure it out.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to write the code to figure out the highest and least amount of rain fall, but I don't know how to get it to actually say which actual month in the output.

You can return the month rather than returning the highest rainfall in that month as follows:

```
public static int mostRainMonth(double[] rainFall)
{
  double highest = rainFall[0];
  int month = index;
  for (int index = 0; index < rainFall.length; index++)
  {
    if (rainFall[index] > highest)
    {
       highest = rainFall[index];
       month = index;
    }
  }

  return month;
}
```

You can then use this method in as follows:

```
int highestRainMonth = mostRainMonth(rainfall);
System.out.println("The month with the highest amount of rain is " +     
        rainfall[highestRainMonth]+" in the month "+highestRainMonth);
```

> Another issue I'm having is with the Decimal Format. I've put the import statement at the top, and I put what I thought was the right code in what I thought was the right place in the body, yet when the average is calculated, it still produces a long string of numbers. ie 12.12121314141, when I want it to display 12.1.

You have just initialized the `DecimalFormatter` object, but you haven't used it anywhere.
You can use the `setMaximumFractionDigits` method as follows:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##0.0");
System.out.println("The average rainfall for this year is " + 
        formatter.format(averageRain(rainFall)));
```